# using single mobile website in a web view for mobile apps

Tags: android, ios, mobile, web

if you want to make a service for people to use where the functions can all be made available via a web interface (website)  And then you wanted to make apps android/ios/windows phone/blackberry

is it easier/possible to make a mobile website which is then wrapped into ALL mobile platforms as apps?
  So the apps will simply show a web view with the mobile site?

do the various App stores (like play) allow this?

Answer (score 0):

iOS specifically does not allow this. Per current Apple review guidelines:

"2.12 Apps that are not very useful, unique, are simply web sites bundled as Apps, or do not provide any lasting entertainment value may be rejected"

https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/

You can pretty safely count on it being rejected if it's just a website in a native wrapper. If you can provide some type of native functionality, even if it's not extensive, you can likely get around this.

Comment: but it say MAY get rejected.  What if the site has things like take pictures, using the phones camera?

Comment: It can never be said with 100% certainty what Apple will reject or not in a given review. They may reject something they approved before, especially in cases like this.

While it says "may be rejected", it is clear that their intention is to not allow apps that are just a wrapper for a mobile site. You can certainly try it, but you would be better off adding some native elements around the web view.

Comment: For instance, if you just made it a two tab application using a tab bar where one tab was your site and the other was a contact page or something that let people email you directly from the app with feedback, that would stand a much better chance of getting approved. Whether that is a good experience for your users, however, is another conversation.